# Write failure on transfer while installing FreeBSD 6.4

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso

I've been trying to install FreeBSD 6.4 on Oracle VirtualBox. I create a new 32-bit FreeBSD virtual machine with 4.00 GB but when I try to install it, it gives me this error:

```
Write failure on Transfer! (wrote -1 bytes of 1425408 bytes)
```

I check the debugging information and it gives me this:

```
...
/stand/cpio: write error: No space left on device
/stand/gunzip: failed fwrite
pid 73 (cpio), uid 0 inumber 13726 on /mnt/usr: filesystem full
...
```

Quick rundown on the installation:

```
Press 1 for: Boot FreeBSD [default]
I select: Standard installation.
On FDISK Partition Editor: <Press A> Use Entire Disk
While ad0s1 is highlighted: <Press S> Set Bootable, then <Press Q>
Select: Standart Install a standard MBR (no boot manager)
On FreeBSD Disklable Editor: Partition name: ad0s1 Free: 8906625 blocks (4348MB)
<Press A> Auto Defaults, <Press Q>
For Choose Distributions: Developer
For Installation Media: CD/DVD
Then finally: Write failure on transfer!
```

It has 4.00GB I don't understand how there's no space left. Is there something in the creating of the virtual machine or installation that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember default 6.4 used partitions within the slices, meaning `/usr` would be something like `ad0s1d`. Most likely the default assigned diskspace for that partition is not big enough for what you are trying to accomplish.

Check the sysinstall's mount point assignment screen to see how much it is allocating to each partition within the slice.

Developer distribution installs `/usr/src`, does it not? If so, that generally is a few GB already. My current checked out version on 11-CURRENT is 3.5 GB already.